# Grad-cam always placing the heatmap in the same area

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, vision

Here is the part of my code relevant to the issue:

```
def forward_hook(module,input,output):
    activation.append(output)

def backward_hook(module,grad_in,grad_out):
    grad.append(grad_out[0])


model.layer4[-1].register_forward_hook(forward_hook)
model.layer4[-1].register_backward_hook(backward_hook)
grad=[]
activation=[]


loader_iter = iter(dataloader_test)
for _ in range(50):
    data, target, meta = next(loader_iter)       
    count1 = 0
    for d, t, m in zip(data, target, meta):

        hm_dogs = []
        heatmap = []
        d, t = map(lambda x: x.to(device), (d, t))
        
        #remove batch size
        d = d.unsqueeze(0)
        output = model(d)

        output[:, 4].backward()
        #get the gradients and activations collected in the hook
        grads=grad[count1].cpu().data.numpy().squeeze()
        fmap=activation[count1].cpu().data.numpy().squeeze()
```

I printed the grads and they are all looking the same despite the iteration. Anyone have some ideas for me?

Comment: https://github.com/saurabheights/DiabeticRetinopathyDetection/blob/master/src/visualization/gradcam.py  Cant help much since your code is not easily reproducible, but you can look at this code. You can also check torchray repo - https://github.com/facebookresearch/TorchRay/blob/master/torchray/attribution/grad_cam.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like you are accumulating the gradients and activations for each iteration of the loop. clear the `grad` and `activation` lists at the start of each iteration, right before the inner loop.

```
loader_iter = iter(dataloader_test)
for _ in range(50):
    grad.clear()
    activation.clear()

    data, target, meta = next(loader_iter)
    count1 = 0
    for d, t, m in zip(data, target, meta):
        hm_dogs = []
        heatmap = []
        d, t = map(lambda x: x.to(device), (d, t))

        # remove batch size
        d = d.unsqueeze(0)
        output = model(d)

        output[:, 4].backward()
        # get the gradients and activations collected in the hook
        grads = grad[count1].cpu().data.numpy().squeeze()
        fmap = activation[count1].cpu().data.numpy().squeeze()
```